Python generic function to read text file into data structure
Is this a proper way to read data from a text file into a data structure in python in order to handle all possible exceptions whilst remaining agnostic to the structure and content of the input data and robust to race conditions on checks?
def read_file_to_struct(file_path, data_struct, sep=None):
    """Read data from a text file into a data structure.
    
    Keyword arguments:
    file_path -- absolute path to a file.
    data_struct -- type of data structure to be returned:
        - string: one string holding all data;
        - list: one list entry per line;
        - dict: one key/value pair per line;
    sep -- separator to split:
        - key/value pairs of dict;
    
    Returns a data structure corresponding to data_struct value.
    """
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            if data_struct == 'list':
                content = file.readlines()
            elif data_struct == 'dict':
                content = {
                    key:value for 
                    line in file for 
                    key, value in [line.split(sep, 1)]
                }
            elif data_struct == 'string':
                content = file.read()
        return(content)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File {} not found.".format(file_path))
    except IsADirectoryError:
        print("{} is a directory, file missing.".format(file_path))
    except EOFError:
        print("No data could be read in file {}.".format(file_path))
    except UnicodeTranslateError:
        print("Unicode translation error on file {}.".format(file_path))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print("Unicode decode error on file {}.".format(file_path))
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print("Unicode encode error on file {}.".format(file_path))
    except UnicodeError:
        print("Unicode error on file {}.".format(file_path))
    except MemoryError:
        print("Out of memory while reading file {}.".format(file_path))
    except PermissionError:
        print("Permission error on file {}.".format(file_path))
    except IOError:
        print("I/O error while reading file {}.".format(file_path))
    except OSError:
        print("OS error while reading file {}.".format(file_path))
    except RuntimeError:
        print("Runtime error while reading file {}.".format(file_path))


Given that each exception message prints more or less the same information, there are simpler ways to do it, without having to code every case. See the Python page on Exception and Exception groups.
